# Trouble deploying React app on static Nginx server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am having issues getting my React app to work on a remote server. I have Nginx setup with the following `conf`

```
server {
    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    xxx.xxx.x.x;
    root           /var/www/my-site;
    index          index.html;

    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  3;
    gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/javascript image/*;
}
```

To confirm Nginx works I put an `index.html` in `/var/www/my-site` and indeed it works and there are no issue.

I then `cd` to `/var/www/my-site` and clone the react project from git. Then I run `npm run build`. I'm not sure what I have to do next.

I tried `serve -s build` and I get:

```
ERROR: Cannot copy to clipboard: write EPIPE

   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                  │
   │   Serving!                                       │
   │                                                  │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:5000      │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:5000   │
   │                                                  │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

However when I point my browser to the servers address I get nothing (I deleted the original index.html). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reverse proxy should work but it's not acceptable to use it for production server, please look over other solutions for that

```
server {
    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    xxx.xxx.x.x;
    root           /var/www/my-site;
    index          index.html;

    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  3;
    gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/javascript image/ ;

    location /my-site/  {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000      ;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }   
 }
```

More on reverse proxies [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)